# Looking for alternative to jQuery .load() events

Tags: jquery

It looks like `.load()` events has been deprecated, per jQuery docs, and I am looking for a cross browser solution to load a page (including scripts) and then fire off a redirect.

```
$( window ).load(function() {
     //redirect code here
});
```

Here is the `.load` events [doc](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)...

From what I can tell, this is also not a reliable solution but I am not sure what a correct/reliable solution would be best for my scenario.

I am unable to function/document.ready as I need to make sure scripts do load before I can redirect.

Any thoughts/direction would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(document).on('load', function(){});` instead of `$(document).load(function(){});` and it is not deprecated.

So use event handler method [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thanks. Would this also be cross browser reliable (assuming JS is enabled on the browser)?